# Add a restriction to a regex expression

Tags: python, regex

Out of hundreds of thousands of words, two examples --

```
JANE_FONDA_AM_PM_YOGA_FOR_BEGINNERS
JANE_FONDA_EN
```

The output I need for this is:

```
JANE_FONDA_AM_PM_YOGA_FOR_BEGINNERS
JANE_FONDA
```

The regex I have come up with is:

```
vendor_id_stem = re.sub(r'(_[A-Za-z_]*|_?[A-Za-z]{2,4}?\d?)$', "", vendor_id)
```

It currently gives me:

```
JANE # BAD
JANE_FONDA # GOOD
```

What I need it to do is make sure that if there isn't an ending such as "en001", it doesn't strip anything, how would I modify the existing regex expression to do this?

Comment: *What I need it to do is make sure that if there isn't an ending such as "en001"* .. But there isn't *en001* at the end of you second string. So what tells you that you that you want to strip `_EN` but not `_BEGINNERS`?

Comment: don't forget to vote-up my answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
vendor_id_stem = re.sub(r'(_[A-Za-z]*|_?[A-Za-z]{2,4}?\d?)$', "", vendor_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "JANE_FONDA_EN"
s.replace(/_EN.*[^_]/, '');

> "JANE_FONDA"
```